# Mailman ignore mm_cfg.py

Tags: linux, debian, mailman

I installed mailman on a debian server with apache on it. I followed instructions to configure the URL of the admin pannel of mailman. So I made the modifications I had to do in /etc/mailman/mm_cfg.py. So now I got this [mm_cfg.py](https://gist.github.com/karlito139/f54b6b271ac27da7fd30).

After that I restart mailman : /etc/init.d/mailman restart.

Now if I create a new list it's admin panel is on serveur2.martobre.fr instead of lists.martobre.fr, as specified in the mm_cfg.py.

If I do a `withlist -l -r fix_url maillinglist` it doesnt change anything. But if it do a `withlist -l -r fix_url maillinglist --urlhost=lists.martobre.fr`, it solve the problem.

I'd like to know why my default configuration is ignored.

Thanks a lot.